# Conditional operation inside a loop, the java 8 way

Tags: java, java-8

I have a for loop which runs different methods based on a value of the looped object. The plain old Java way is like this

```
for(Object obj : inputList){
    if(1 == obj.intVar){
        executeFirst();
    } else if (2 == obj.intVar) {
        executeSecond();
    } else {
        executeDefault();
    }
}
```

or by using a simple switch case. 
I know I can use something like below in Java 8. But for me, it seems like a fusion between Java 7 & 8. I am not sure if I can use a **filter/map/reduce** here as the intent is not data manipulation, but to derive a particular behaviour. Is there any way we can do this in pure Java 8 way or is this the way to do it?

```
inpultList.stream().forEach(obj -> {
    if(1 == obj.intVar){
        executeFirst();
    } else if (2 == obj.intVar) {
        executeSecond();
    } else {
        executeDefault();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a point in using Streams in this example, but a switch statement seems better than if.

Comment: Also, `1 == obj.intVar` is unconventional, and doesn't have any advantage over `obj.intVar == 1`. This is not C. integers aren't booleans. `if (obj.intVar = 1)` won't compile.

Comment: Java 8 didn't change the basic functionality of the language. It certainly didn't change `for` loops. If you insist on writing things in "pure Java 8 way", you'll just be wasting valuable development time on irrelevant syntax modification.

Comment: Also the usual rule is that if you have working code, the question belongs on Code Review, not here. These questions on converting loops to streams should be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a bit over-engineered for your simple example, but a general solution is to use a `Map` with handlers:

```
Map<Integer,Runnable> handlers = new HashMap<>();
handlers.put(1, () -> executeFirst());
handlers.put(2, () -> executeSecond());
```

```
inputList.stream()
    .map(obj -> handlers.getOrDefault(obj.intVar, () -> executeDefault()))
    .forEach(Runnable::run);
```

or

```
inputList.forEach(obj -> handlers.getOrDefault(obj.intVar, () -> executeDefault()).run());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not bad, I propose only to avoid the use of `stream`, you don't need it.

```
inpultList.forEach(l -> {
        if (l.intVar == 1) executeFirst();
        else if (l.intVar == 2) executeSecond();
        else executeDefault();
});
```

I disagree with @Kayaman, I don't think that is a waste of time trying to use java 8 expression, because they allow that we can easily distribute processing of collection over multiple threads.

However, I do not encourage the use of `filter` in this case because you'll be going over the same list multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on using the Stream API you could do

```
inputList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.intVar == 1).forEach(this::executeFirst);
inputList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.intVar == 2).forEach(this::executeSecond);
inputList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.intVar > 2).forEach(this::executeDefault);
```

That being said: you should always stick to what is most readable and maintainable - a language feature being available does not mean you *have to* use it. I would stick to the "plain old Java" way in your case.

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing: the order of the execution is different, and the third condition isn't the same as in the original code.